# Is there a single word that is the opposite of "want" (i.e. "do not want")?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there a single verb that means "do not want"?

E.g. "I want that object" or "I want to do this" vs. "I _____ *(do not want)* that object" or "I _____ *(do not want)* to do this"?

Also in the case of casual writing, when you might write "Let's not talk about what you want/don't want, let's take action instead" or "Let's not talk about what you do or do not want, let's take action instead", is there a single-word opposite of "want" that could be dropped in and used in combination with "want" in that type of sentence?

Comment: No, there isn't. There are a number of verbs that include this concept, but none that is simply the negative of _want_ in all of its uses. That's why we have [negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), so we don't have to memorize a different verb every time we want to negate one.

Comment: @JohnLawler Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Willy-nilly...Will he, nill he? or, does he want or does he not?  Sadly, this useful pairing is now only used in its highly reduced, contracted, and adverbial form.

Comment: I'm rather surprised with the many answers (with up votes) that (mis-)understand the situation of the question: Not wanting is **not** bitterly hating something -- *abhor*, *detest* ..., *eschew*, *dislike* -- none of them is related to 'not want.' I would think this is so simple.

Comment: Jason, I don't want to disappoint you but Prof Lawler is right, only *not want* can mean that.

Comment: @Kris I know, his comment was the best answer, as disappointing as the fact is. That's why I asked him to post it as an answer, and why I am giving some time before I accept one. :)

Comment: Note, however, that John Lawler's comment doesn't apply everywhere. There are verbs that do have other verbs as opposites, even if those mean exactly the same as the negations with "not".

Comment: I **decline/refuse** to answer this question, because I **don't want** to answer it.

Comment: a quotation dating to 1447 in OED. *Yf þou nylt, I shal..[thee] neuer more doughtir calle.*

Comment: This where elision is so handy. *"Let's not talk about what you want or not, let's take action instead"* is short and doesn't require the listener to wonder if eschew or reject or whatnot mean the opposite of want.

Comment: @KateGregory Oh, that's a great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: At least according to Chinese subtitles, "[do not want](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/do-want-do-not-want)" is equivalent to the single-word interjection "[Noooooo!](http://www.geekosystem.com/do-not-want-origin/)"

Comment: Related: [How do I say 'I don't want' without phrasing it in terms of wanting?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316629). The two questions, **as formulated**, are not the same, but some of the answers to that question, due to a misunderstanding of the question, ended up, effectively, answering this one, just like some of the answers in this page are, effectively, answering the other one.

Answer (score 7):

Consider using *dislike*.

> I **dislike** that broom.
>
> I **dislike** sweeping the floor.

Comment: I like this one, thanks; it's not the *exact* meaning of "do not want" but it implies it and has about the same strength (not too extreme).

Answer (score 3):

The term **[eschew](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/eschew)** means

> to keep away from (something harmful or disliked); shun; avoid; abstain from

However, it seems a bit more active than the obverse of *want*.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the responses are a bit too strong to be opposites of *want*. I voted for *dislike*, but I'll also suggest [*avoid*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoid).

> 1. To keep away from; to keep clear of; to endeavor not to meet; to shun; to abstain from.

In your examples "I avoid that object" and "I avoid doing that" seem to fit nicely as opposites to *want*.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there are a lot of strong words here. I like "avoid" too, although it is similar to "reject" in that "want" sort of describes a feeling or desire that you have, where "avoid" and "reject" describe an action that you take. For example, you can avoid/reject something *and* want it at the same time.

Comment: @JasonC That's an interesting point! But do opposite words *have* to be exclusive? I have a love/hate relationship with lots of things. :)

Answer (score 3):

I read a lot of the answers here, and many people suggested 'abhor' or 'reject.' These words don't really reverse 'want,' though, because they add so much negative emotion.  'Diswant' is a lovely word, I wish it was real.

"Do you want to go for a walk in the lovely sunshine instead of reading that silly old Jane Austen book?"

"No, I diswant to go for a walk, and I want to read." - what I want to say.
"No, I abhor going for a walk, and I want to read."   - too much vehemence about the walk
"No, I reject your offer to walk, I want to read."    - rejection of the person?  how rude.

Comment: Hello, Sylvia. I agree, 'diswant' sounds quite pleasant. However, the ethos of the site is to focus on the language as it is, and as it is reasonably likely to develop; do-it-yourself 'unwords' (sorry) are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I might choose [abhor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abhor),

> **abhor**   *verb*
>
> to regard with extreme repugnance or aversion; detest utterly; loathe; abominate.

Or, *detest*, *loathe* or [despise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/despise?s=t)

> **despise**   *verb*
>
> to regard with contempt, distaste, disgust, or disdain; scorn; loathe.

Answer (score 1):

**Reject** appears to be the closest single verb opposite of *want* but it depends on the context. There is no exact opposite of **want**, except the negation **not want**.

> **reject:** to refuse to take something, for example because it is damaged or is not what you wanted - *[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/reject_1)*
>
> **reject:** *transitive.* To refuse to have or accept for some purpose; to set aside or discard as useless or worthless; to turn down. Also *intransitive*. - *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161716)*

I believe *reject* covers most senses of *not want*.

---

**Disincline** is an option also (but again, it is not an exact opposite). It covers different levels of unwillingness, and it is both transitive and intransitive.

> to not want to do something - *[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disinclined)*

---

Although, **diswant** could be an apt neologism.

There is an interesting approach regarding semantic primitives from the book "Semantics : Primes and Universals *By Anna Wierzbicka*":

> In postulating “diswanting’ rather than negation as a semantic primitive,
> I was trying to come to grips with the fact that the semantic relation
> between the phrases “I want” and “I don’t want” seems to be different from
> that between, say, “I know” and “I don’t know”, or “I do” and “I don’t
> do”. “I don’t know” (or “I don’t do”) means, roughly speaking, that ‘It is
> not the case that I know (or do)’. “I don’t want”, however (on one reading
> at least), does not seem to mean that ‘it is not the case that I want’ (as in
> “I don’t particularly want”); rather, it seems to mean that I positively ‘dis-
> want’ something. It is also true that the interjection No! can be used to
> express a strong ‘diswant’ (“rejection”), rather than merely a denial of wanting. By assuming that ‘diswanting’ was semantically simpler than
> negation, I seemed to be able to explain such facts. (What was more diffi-
> cult to explain in that approach was the use of negation in declarative sen-
> tences—a point to which I will return below.)

Comment: "Reject" could work in some cases, although it's more of an "action" than a "feeling", if that makes sense, but I like this one. Thanks! P.S. Wow, that's a really fascinating point she makes in that passage, I never thought about that before.

Answer (score 1):

Consider "exclude," "detest," and "execrate."

> exclude: consider that something is not worth attention.

E.g.

In business and in life, we can get forward by doing things others exclude [=don't want] to do.

[This is a rule that I vehemently exclude from my tournaments, as we've lost more than a few rounds due to this ridiculous rule.](http://www.hsquizbowl.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1876)

> detest: to abhor; dislike intensely.

Let the child -- say, a daughter -- be happy, let her be miserable, let her deeply desire this or deeply detest that.

> execrate: to detest utterly.

What scope is there for the stronger emotions if the orator is not to his speech, to flame out in anger, to reproach, to wish or to execrate?

Answer (score 1):

It's a stretch.... BUT they are single-words

**Repudiate** and **refuse**

- I want + [noun] = *I want prosperity*
- I repudiate + [noun] = *I repudiate prosperity*
- I want to [verb] = *I want to go*
- I refuse to [verb] = *I refuse to go*

> Let's not talk about what **you want** or **repudiate**, let's take action
>   instead
>   Let's not talk about what you **want to do** or **refuse to do**, let's take action
>   instead

Answer (score 0):

How about the verb 'to resent sth', 'to resent doing sth', 'to resent sb doing sth'?

Here is what the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* says:

> resent /ri'zent/ [transitive]
>
> to feel angry or upset about a situation or about something that someone has done, especially because you think that it is not fair; resent (somebody) doing something; bitterly/deeply/strongly resent
>
> *I resented having to work such long hours.*
>
> *She bitterly resented his mother's influence over him.*
>
> *Paul  resented the fact that  Carol didn't trust him.*

*I **resented having** (= **did not want to have**) to work such long hours.*

*She **bitterly resented** (= **did not at all want**) his mother's influence over him.*

*Paul **resented the fact that Carol didn't** (= **did not want Carol not to**) trust him.*

Of course you cannot resent something that does not exist, whereas you can 'not want' it.

*I do not want a third world war.*   * *I resent a third world war.* *

but then, just adding the phrase 'the idea of' does the trick:

*I **do not want** (= **resent the idea of**) a third world war.*

Answer (score -4):

Everyone is taking the wrong approach to the question, " What is the opposite of 'want'"? The negative is not necessarily the opposite, i.e. want and not want. The opposite of want is "need". 
You're welcome

Comment: The question specifically assumes the opposite of "want" is "do not want".